# is there a way to redirect from a url that is created by java backend to the reset-password page in next.js?

Tags: next.js

my java backend create this link(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/account/reset/finish?key=vljKlxjYh6Cd2xp119bQ`) for the user to click and get into the reset-password page so he/she can reset their password.
my backend api is /api/account/reset-password/finish

how can i redirect the user from the link to this api in next.js .

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you want. Do you want the path `/account/reset/finish` in your Next.js app to redirect to the Next.js API route `/api/account/reset-password/finish`?

Answer (score 0):

You first have to create the `account/reset/finish/index.js` page in pages folder of the nextjs app, and whenever the link is clicked the route automatically will load that page.

Then in that page you can access the `key` from query search params.